# Action does not trigger a reducer in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-promise

I'm new to redux and trying to fetch content using the Contentful API. For some reason the action I call does not reach the reducer. I have attached the code I feel is relevant and any contributions would be highly appreciated.

actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_BASE_URL = 'https://cdn.contentful.com';
const API_SPACE_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const API_KEY ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

const FETCH_CONTENT = 'fetch_content';

export function fetchContent() {
  const request = axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/spaces/${API_SPACE_ID}/environments/master/entries?access_token=${API_KEY}`);
  return {
    type: FETCH_CONTENT,
    payload: request
  };
  }
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import ContentReducer from './reducer-content';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  contents: ContentReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

reducer-content.js

```
import {FETCH_CONTENT} from '../actions';
const INITIAL_STATE = { all: [] };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_CONTENT:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload.data.items };

  default:
  return state;
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import { logger } from 'redux-logger'


import ContentIndex from './components/content-index';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise, logger)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
      <Route  path = "/" component = {ContentIndex}/>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

components/content-index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {fetchContent} from '../actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';

class ContentIndex extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchContent();
  }

  renderContent(props){
    return this.props.contents.map((content, index) => {
      return (
        <article key={content.sys.id}>
          <h3>{content.fields.name}</h3>
          <p>{content.fields.website}</p>
        </article>
      );
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <h3>Content</h3>
      {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {contents: state.contents.all};
}
// export default CharacterIndex;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchContent})(ContentIndex);
```

Comment: Like devserkan said, you need an async action, because axios always returns promises, not the data of the response directly. An async function is the easiest way to handle that, but you need to have the right middleware in redux.

Comment: It seems that `redux-promise` waits a promise, I guessed that wrong. So, when you put a `console.log` in your action creator and your reducer, where it fails? I mean where is it stopped being logged?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

It seems that I'm wrong here (Thanks to @Dave Newton's comments). `redux-promise` waits a promise and if it receives one, resolves it and dispatches the value. So, using an async function and using an action creator here is useless.

---

You are using `redux-promise`, I don't know how it handles the situation but in its Github repo there is an example with `redux-actions` and it uses an async function. I'm  more familiar with `redux-thunk` but probably it suits in your situation to use an async action creator here.

Try this:

```
export async function fetchContent() {
  const request = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/spaces/${API_SPACE_ID}/environments/master/entries?access_token=${API_KEY}`);
  return {
    type: FETCH_CONTENT,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Comment: In redux-promise it expects the payload to be the promise; when the promise resolves the reducer is called with the resolved promise (but not if it rejects). Here you're just creating a normal action, which is fine, but makes redux-promise pointless.

Comment: @DaveNewton, so am I wrong here? First, I suspected that but after seeing `redux-actions` example I though it needs the resolved data. https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-promise

Comment: "If it receives a promise, it will dispatch the resolved value of the promise. It will not dispatch anything if the promise rejects." If you do an async/await you're just creating a regular (async) action. Which is fine, but makes redux-promise seem not that helpful anymore. (Although I stopped using redux-promise for other reasons anyway, it was a useful abstraction for awhile.)

Comment: Got it. I missed that part and look through the example. This confused me. I am going to update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @devserkan I think that all makes sense to me now. However, i'm not getting an error in my console stating: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined.

Comment: @devserkan It looks like its in my action fetchContent. If I pull the async off it goes away.

Comment: So, maybe there is a problem on fetching from API?

Answer (score 0):

axios.get() returns promise.

So you need use async / await.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code and avoid dispatching asynchronous actions and needing to use redux middleware by doing the following:

- Convert `fetchContent()` into an async function that returns an action with the items in the payload
- create a `mapDispatchToProps` that creates a function that dispatches the action returned by `fetchContent()`

`fetchContent()` would look like this:

```
export async function fetchContent() {
  const request = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}/spaces/${API_SPACE_ID}/environments/master/entries?access_token=${API_KEY}`);
  return {
    type: FETCH_CONTENT,
    payload: request.data.items
  };
}
```

`connect` would look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {contents: state.contents.all};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadItems: () => fetchContent().then(action => dispatch(action))
  }
}

// export default CharacterIndex;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContentIndex);
```

your reducer would look like this:

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_CONTENT:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload };

  default:
  return state;
  }
}
```

and `componentDidMount()` would look like this:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.loadItems();
  }
```

Comment: @JaredMudd friendly reminder to accept an answer if it provides the needed info